# Selinum WebDriver, Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to compare three strings getting from three different pages.I am 
    using below code but unable to proceed. Please check code in the end.Can any 
    one help me please.
    Main problem i am not getting idea how to compare three string from 
    different pages.
    When i have written compare code in if block, getting error "The left-hand 
    side of an assignment must be a variable"

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;



public class test {
static String Price;
static String InnerPrice;
static String CartPrice;
public static void main (String args[])
{
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
"./Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']")).
sendKeys("Iphone 7");


driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='nav-input' and 
@value='Go']")).click();
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='a-expander-prompt' and 
text()='See more']")).click();
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='a-size-small a-color-base' 
and text()='Smartphones & Basic Mobiles']")).click();
try {
Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch (Exception e1) {
System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
}


driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Smartphones')]")).
click();
Select select=new 
Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='sort']")));
select.selectByVisibleText("Price: Low to High");

try {
Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch (Exception e) {

System.out.println("Exception is"+e.getMessage());
}

List<WebElement> myElements = 
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='a-size-base a-color-price s-
price a-text-bold']"));
//System.out.println("Size of List: "+myElements.size());
int size=myElements.size();
for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
Price=myElements.get(i).getAttribute("innerText");
System.out.println("Price of Search Result Page is " +Price);
break;

}
myElements.get(0).click();


String parent=driver.getWindowHandle();

// This will return the number of windows opened by Webdriver and will 
return Set of St//rings
Set<String>s1=driver.getWindowHandles();

// Now we will iterate using Iterator
Iterator<String> I1= s1.iterator();

while(I1.hasNext())
{

String child_window=I1.next();

// Here we will compare if parent window is not equal to child window then 
we will close

if(!parent.equals(child_window))
{
driver.switchTo().window(child_window);

//System.out.println(driver.switchTo().window(child_window).getTitle());
String 


InnerPrice=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='priceblock_ourprice']"))
.getText();
System.out.println("Price of Product Details Page is 
"+InnerPrice.substring(0,InnerPrice.length()-3));

//To Add product in cart

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='add-to-cart-button']")).click();
try {
Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

String CartPrice=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='huc-v2-order-row-
inner']//div[@class='a-row a-spacing-micro']//span[starts-with(@style,'text-
decoration:')]")).getText();
System.out.println("Cart Price is "+CartPrice.substring(0, 
CartPrice.length()-3));

driver.close();
}


// once all pop up closed now switch to parent window
driver.switchTo().window(parent);

}
If (Price.equalsIgnoreCase(InnerPrice))&& 
(InnerPrice.equalsIgnoreCase(CartPrice))
{
System.out.println("Equal");
}

 }

 }
```

Comment: Check your if statement. parenthesis are not correct

Comment: Please post an [mcve], identify the line that is throwing the error, post the full error, and some description of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

In the if case, you have

```
If (Price.equalsIgnoreCase(InnerPrice))&& (InnerPrice.equalsIgnoreCase(CartPrice))
```

You are closing the if statement too early. No need to put the **equalsIgnoreCase** method call within braces. Try with

```
If (Price.equalsIgnoreCase(InnerPrice)&& InnerPrice.equalsIgnoreCase(CartPrice))
```

Comment: @Andrei...Even if i am not putting any braces then also i am getting error...not after running the code but on if statement itself....a red under line...when i hover mouse on it, in tool tip it says "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable"

Comment: @Ashu We can't see what you are seeing. You need to update your question with more specific details. See my comment above.

Comment: @JeffC-I searched an item in amazon and sort it with lowest price first. capture the cheapest price from there (Say Price).Then i clicked on product price and reached om product details page,captured price from product details page (Say InnerPrice).Finally i added the same product into cart and captured price from there (CartPrice).Now i want to compare all three price-if(Price.equalsIgnoreCase(InnerPrice))&&(InnerPrice.equalsIgnoreCase(CartPrice)){}.But as soon as i am puttin if block,gettin red under line,mouse hovering on it saying "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable"